# Designing an (RL) agent for a graph-based music improvisation system

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, graphs

I am trying to implement a simple agent that creates sounds by building up signal building blocks (e.g. sound generators, filters etc.) that can generally be connected in the form of a directed acyclic graph, and each module has quasi-continuous parameter inputs (defined intervals of floating point numbers, e.g. for a frequency, an amplitude etc.). This agent should be able to operate in real-time along with me as a human agent.

My idea is to use something like **reinforced learning** as it allows to operate in an exploratory mode where the state space is very large if not infinite, something that I understand is a disadvantage in a learning-by-example (supervised) mode.

- Do you consider **RL applicable** in this scenario?
- How would I go about **defining the state space**? Is every module (generator or filter) a cell in that space? How about their connections and parameters? Should I introduce a partial ordering of the graph, or radically simplify the state? Perhaps the state should be a feature vector of the actually produced sound instead of the graph structure?
- I am thinking that I have to provide the **rewards manually** depending on whether the current result is musically meaningful or bad. Does that make sense? Is there any literature for this "human evaluated" RL? I know there are human fitness functions in genetic programming, so I am thinking this would be an analogous situation.
- I am worried about the convergence rate. In automatic learning, I can easily perform thousands of steps, but if I have to assign manual reward and I have to listen to the actual sound production, the agent can only act at a fraction of the speed.